# Может ли работать приложение в фоне на IOS? Работа со вспышкой камеры

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, apple

Собственно, вопрос в названии темы.

Задача в том, чтобы, один раз запустив прогу на телефоне, при получении смс задняя вспышка медленно загоралась и тухла, как бы делая нотификацию юзера, но при этом телефоном моно было бы пользоваться, там лазать в интернете и так далее. Что скажут знатоки?

Comment: @diamond151, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого не надо писать программу, это родная настройка в iOS.

Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> LED Flash for Alerts

Answer (score 0):

По смс нельзя, по пуш уведомлению можно.

Comment: А прога может, считывать смс ящик, и автоматом при приходе смски, конвертировать это событие в пуш уведомление?

Comment: @diamond151 В iOS нет доступа к сообщениям или звонкам. Нельзя получить уведомление о приходе СМС или о входящем звонке. И тем более прочитать сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Изучите многозадачность)

Да и гугел знает уйму разжеванных ответов)

Например, неограниченная работа в фоновом режиме :

```
Проигрывание аудио: Приложения которые проигрывают аудиопоток в фоновом режиме, например тот же Instacast, воспроизводящий аудиоподкаст.

Отслеживание местоположение через GPS: Навигационные и другие приложения, отслеживающие местоположение устройства в реальном времени и сообщающие пользователю различные данные так же могут работать в Фоновом режиме неограниченно долгое время.

Мониторинг VoIP соединений: Приложения типа Skype и Viber, которые отслеживают входящие звонки через VoIP сети, также работают в iOS постоянно.

Приложения Киоска: Все загрузки «Киоска» идут в фоновом режиме и не прекращаются.

Сопряженные с аксессуарами приложения: Все приложения, которые получают входящие данные с различных подключенных к iOS-устройству аксессуаров не прекращают свою работу, пока подключено устройство.
```